# What is the Difference between CFUrl and NSUrl

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest, cfnetwork

I would like to send a simple HTTP to a web server in Objective-C.
From what i've seen, the most common way is to use the NSURLRequest with NSUrl....
But i have also stumbled upon the CFNetwork Library which can also be used to communicate with web servers. So my question is : what is the difference between the 2 methods and which one should i use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFNetwork is a lower-level C-based library, whereas `NSURL` and friends are part of the higher level Foundation framework.

Foundation should cater to all your needs for communicating with web servers via HTTP. Notable classes to look at are `NSURL`, `NURLConnection`, `NSURLRequest` (and it's mutable friend `NSMutableURLRequest`).

You should be able to build up complex requests, including things like multi-part form requests using Foundation objects and not having to go down into the CFNetwork library.

CFNetwork is useful for when you start to look at creating and managing your own sockets and streams (although, Foundation can do this too).

Answer (score 2):

`CFUrlRef` is toll free bridged with `NSURL *`: you can use them interchangeably. In general the cfnetwork stuff is lower level than the `NSURLRequest` stuff - only drop down to it if you need to.